# Javascript: eval behavior in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, eval

Please consider the example at http://jsfiddle.net/KE8Mv/

HTML

```
<input type='text' id="log" />
```

JavaScript

```
var f = function(){
    if(console && console.log)
        console.log('hello eval issue!');
}.toString();

var f1 = eval('('+f+')');

var logMsg = f1===undefined?'eval returns none':'eval returns function';

$('#log').val(logMsg);
```

The eval invoke returns function() object in FF and Chrome, but returns undefined in IE8:(
What might be the issue? How to get the same behavior in all the browsers?

Answer (score 4):

If you *really* want to do it like this, you can create an anonymous function that will return you the function you need:

```
var f1 = eval("(function() {return " + f + ";})()");
```

**Edit**: Or even simpler (it is only necessary to make the browser consider this an expression with the function being the result of that expression, so we can use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator)):

```
var f1 = eval("0, " + f);
```

But you might want to consider using the [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) that takes the function body as a string.